# how to specify nested generics in eclipse

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I want to specify this type:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> blah = null;
```

But Eclipse refuses this. I am not sure if it is Eclipse or the Java parser.

I had similar issues when trying to write my own java parser at study times: ">>" was regarded as the shift operator.

What's going on here?

Edit: java works for this.

Comment: Why not actually specify what happens instead "Eclipse refuses this". If I paste that code in my eclipse, I see no problems.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because your eclipse is set up to use a compiler version for java 1.4 which doesn't have generics.

Does it work if you just do

```
Map<String,String> map = null;
```

EDIT: Setting in eclipse
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No problem for me as expexted...

Indeed you can for sure define nested generic like you was doing

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> blah = null;
```

Event doing this will not cause problems

```
Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,String>>> blah = null;
```

It is not a problem of nested generic (Java support this feature), it is a problem of generic support. Be sure to have the right settings for your compiler in Eclipse, you have to set at least java 1.5 for enabling generics. (Windows->Preferences->Java-Compiler and then check the version).